I got AT+CREG? +CREG: 0,0 OK response and at+cops? +COPS: 0 OK Can anyone suggest what is the error occured here
I got AT+CREG?
+CREG: 0,0
OK
response and
at+cops?
+COPS: 0
OK
Can anyone suggest what is the error occured here
The gsm module I have used here is simcom7070g
I got AT+CREG?
+CREG: 0,2
OK
response and
at+cops?
+COPS: should be a value
OK
Please clarify me is this gsm module can work with 4g sim card

Both AT+CREG and AT+COPS are standardized by 3GPP and both in the specification 27.007. Although manufacturers might at least theoretically deviate a little, or perhaps more likely lag a bit behind on the latest version the very best thing is always to use the device specific (e.g. simcom7070g) specification from the manufacturer.
So first seek out the device specification and failing that, use the generic 3gpp specification.

In addition I suspect you will have great benefit from looking into the V.250 specification as well (all of chapter 5 is relevant).
